# date displayed as oracle.sql in IReport

Tags: java, oracle, date, jasper-reports, date-format

- When displaying the date in Ireport it is being displayed as `oracle.sql` instead of actual date[`Ex: 12/4/2012 displayed as oracle.sql`]. I tried changing date formats, but its difficult to determine where i am going wrong.
- The code where the date display as `oracle.sql` is `<![CDATA[""+$F{TIME_REGISTERED}]]>`
  **The code below displays JasperReport:**

  ```
        <textField>
       <reportElement uuid="e20e9b37-a687-400f-9b29-e4a210e2d71f" x="661" y="26" width="55" height="20"/>
       <textElement/>
       <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""+$F{TIME_REGISTERED}]]></textFieldExpression>
         </textField>
  ```

Comment: Did you try changing `<![CDATA[""+$F{TIME_REGISTERED}]]>` to `<![CDATA[$F{TIME_REGISTERED}]]>`. Yours is trying to do string concatenation of an empty string with the data object. That could be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date into String using `SimpleDateFormat` and set this as object variable

Then declare the variable in jrxml

```
<field name="TIME_REGISTERED" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Then use

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TIME_REGISTERED}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: i didn't get the answer,i have to convert the date in String format before saving to the database and then use it in my jasper report by declaring as `<field name="TIME_REGISTERED" class="java.lang.String"/>` ? is this is a way

Comment: Ok, what I mean to say is that, set the date after converting to string in the object that you are passing to jasper not to the database

Answer (score 0):

"As of Date " +  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format($P{asofdate})

$P{asofdate} is a Date.

"As of Date " +  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format($F{asofdate})

$F{asofdate} is a Date.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.